# Optional Variable Group in Azure Pipelines .yaml

Tags: azure, yaml, pipeline

I am trying to create a standardized .yaml template for multiple repositories, however depending on the repository I need to add extra variables, thus an optional variable group. I could not find any documentation on this and asked Copilot for a direction, which led me to this response:

[image: Copilot response]

Looking further into it, it looks like Copilot just made up a tag that would be a convenient solution.

I am aware that I could add a parameter to one of the main variable groups and based on that could choose to load a variable group, but that would clog up the code a bit too much for my taste.

```yaml
variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['usesOptionalGroup'], 'true') }}:
    - group: OptionalGroup
```

Are there different way to include optional variable groups in a .yaml file?

Comment: What is your purpose when you make a variable group optional?

Comment: I want to create optional variable groups so I can have additional parameters depending on the repository, as when you include parameters, they have to have a value. This way I can separate and order parameters for when a repository has a need for more parameters than usual, without adding parameters that would only clog up the main variable groups.

Comment: Furthermore, I want to avoid complicating and needlessly adding to the main variable groups, as that would result in a lot of additional checks in the pipeline, which would impact readability among other things.

Comment: What condition will determine if an optional group is to be loaded or not? Lets say you are able to make a parameter group optional, how do you think the pipeline should determine when the group is to be loaded or not?

Comment: Based on if the variable group has any parameters in it